# How to format labels of points in car::scatter3d?

Tags: r, rgl, r-car

I'm trying to create a 3D scatter plot of a planetary group, each body properly labeled. The next code creates the plot I need.

```
with(bpmg, {
    car::scatter3d(x = X, y = Y,z = Z, 
              surface = FALSE, 
              point.col = color,
              labels = Name,
              id.n = nrow(bpmg))
})
```

[image]

I cannot find in the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/car/versions/2.1-5/topics/scatter3d), however, a way to format the labels of each planet in such a way they don't have that size and/or color. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the `scatter3d` function, but if you used `rgl`'s `plot3d` and `text3d` it's fairly straightforward.  For example,

```
with(bpmg, {
    rgl::plot3d(x = X, y = Y,z = Z, col = color)
    rgl::text3d(x = X, y = Y, z = Z, col = othercolor, adj = c(0,0),
                cex = 2)
})
```

This is untested (you didn't include any data in your question).